# How to add transaction with revenue into list?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, universal-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

To add transaction to Google Analytics page from back-end (Express.js) I have installed `universal-analytics`.

Here is the example of function which is supposed to add products to transactions and revenue:

```js
visitor
    .transaction(transaction.id)
    .item(products[0].product_price, 1, products[0].name)
    .send()
```

But there is a problem, when this piece of code executes, on GA page Product List Performance section, I can see it only in `(not set)` list.

[image]

So, how to fix it? I have not found anything about how to add products in lists. Has someone already implemented that?

Comment: I have looked through the code, and Enhanced E-Commerce is not implemented. You need to look for another module that supports Enhanced E-Commerce in Google Analytics.

Comment: Ok, do you know other modules for `Express.js` that supports Enhanced E-Commerce in Google Analytics?